# how to let validator for textfield allow other language like german russian or arabic, flutter

Tags: flutter, validation

Hi here is the validator for textfield, but I assumed my user is non english speaker, so is there a way to include other language:

```
  validateFolderName(value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'sorry, name could not be empty';
    } else if (!InputValidators.nameValidate(value)) {
      return 'only alphabets and numbers only';
    } else if (value.length >= 20) {
      return 'sorry, name could not be too long';
    }
    return null;
  }

class InputValidators {
  static bool nameValidate(String value) {
    return RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$').hasMatch(value);
  }
}
```

thank you for any clues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
var reg = RegExp(r"^(?:\p{L}\p{Mn}*|\p{N})+$", unicode: true);
```

This will include all letters, numbers and diacritics and other Unicode too

Answer (score 0):

Dart regular expressions have the same syntax and semantics as JavaScript regular expressions. It's regulating by  [ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects)

To validate not only English letters you need:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]
```

this is for non English letters plus

```
\w
```

for English. All together:

```
([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+
```

Abd for Unicode:

```
([^\u0000-\u007F]|\w)+
```